# Python 3 JSON/Dictionary help , not sure how to parse values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am attempting to write out some JSON output into a csv file but first i am trying to understand how the data is structured. I am working from a sample script which connects to an API and pulls down data based a query specified.

The json is returned from the server with this query:

```
response = api_client.get_search_results(search_id, 'application/json')
body = response.read().decode('utf-8')
body_json = json.loads(body)
```

If i perform a

```
print(body_json.keys())
```

i get the following output:

```
dict_keys(['events'])
```

So from this is it right to assume that the entries i am really interested in are another dictionary inside the events dictionary?
If so how can i 'access' them?

Sample JSON data the search query returns to the variable above

```
{
  "events":[
    {
      "source_ip":"10.143.223.172",
      "dest_ip":"104.20.251.41",
      "domain":"www.theregister.co.uk",
      "Domain Path":"NULL",
      "Domain Query":"NULL",
      "Http Method":"GET",
      "Protocol":"HTTP",
      "Category":"NULL",
      "FullURL":"http://www.theregister.co.uk"
    },
    {
      "source_ip":"10.143.223.172",
      "dest_ip":"104.20.251.41",
      "domain":"www.theregister.co.uk",
      "Domain Path":"/2017/05/25/windows_is_now_built_on_git/",
      "Domain Query":"NULL",
      "Http Method":"GET",
      "Protocol":"HTTP",
      "Category":"NULL",
      "FullURL":"http://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/05/25/windows_is_now_built_on_git/"
    },
  ]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried accessing `body_json['events']` yet? This isn't really a JSON issue; you have a straight-up nested datastructure, all Python dictionaries and a list.

Comment: In other words, if you know how to access a value in dictionary or a list, you can work out how to access your data in this structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json.keys() only returns the keys associated with json. 
Here is the code:

```
for key in json_data.keys():
   for i in range(len(json_data[key])):
     key2 = json_data[key][i].keys()
         for k in key2:
                 print k + ":"  + json_data[key][i][k]
```

> Output:

```
 Http Method:GET
 Category:NULL
 domain:www.theregister.co.uk
 Protocol:HTTP
 Domain Query:NULL
 Domain Path:NULL
 source_ip:10.143.223.172
 FullURL:http://www.theregister.co.uk
 dest_ip:104.20.251.41


Http Method:GET
Category:NULL
domain:www.theregister.co.uk
Protocol:HTTP
Domain Query:NULL
Domain Path:/2017/05/25/windows_is_now_built_on_git/
source_ip:10.143.223.172
FullURL:http://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/05/25/windows_is_now_built_on_git/
dest_ip:104.20.251.41
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: yes. Your `body_json` has returned a dictionary with a key of "events" which contains a list of dictionaries.

The best way to 'access' them would be to iterate over them.

A very rudimentary example:

```
    for i in body_json['events']:
        print(i)
```

Of course, during the iteration you could access the specific data that you needed by replacing `print(i)` with `print(i['FullURL'])`and saving it to a variable and so on.

It's important to note that whenever you're working with API's that return a JSON response, you're simply working with dictionaries and Python data structures.

Best of luck.